# Visual Studio Code Not Displaying Invisible Characters/Spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, source-engine

I am currently working on writing code for a Source Game Engine map file. I have issues with Visual Studio Code not displaying certain invisible characters.

When using notepad++, I can see there are invisible characters in between the lines:
[image: When using notepad++, I can see there are invisible characters in between the lines]

But when I open it up in visual studio code, it's as if the invisible character doesn't exist.

This is what I see when using visual studio code:
[image: This is what I see when using visual studio code]

I have asked my friends who also do the same thing (making Source Engine Maps) and they all don't have this issue. One of my friends sent me this image:

This is what he sees in his own editor, with squares representing the invisible character/space:
[image: This is what he sees in his own editor, with squares representing the invisible character/space]

I've done a few things to try to fix this issue:

- Changing fonts (I used a custom font but reset to default to see if it had any impact)
- Changing encoding setting (UTF-8 was what my friends used but I tried tinkering around)
- Changing editors (Tried Atom/Sublime but only Notepad++ even shows there being an invisible character)
- Updated / reinstalled language packs
- Enabling whitespaces

After everything, I still have the same issue. Are there other possible fixes/causes for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** 
I just had to enable `Render Control Characters` in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

I myself, went through this and all I did was:

-> Open Settings(ctrl+,)

-> You will find an icon (settings(JSON))

-> locate this:

```
"editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters": {
    " ": true
}
```

-> change it to:

```
"editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters": {
    "": false
}
```

-> restart application

[have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4asrd.png)

[I could able to spot now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqN7c.png)